# How do I access user's field in show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello people I have a challenge here please someone should help out. I have the models for color and sub_color below and I have the Ids of both sub_color and color in users table. now I want to do something like this in users show.html.erb

<% @user.sub_color.name%> #this is not working

but <% user.email %> #this works. I also tried

<% @user.sub_color.id %> this didn't work too.This gives undefined method 'id' for nil:class.

Anything I am doing wrong please. Thanks in advance.

model for sub_color

has_many :users
belongs_to :color

end

model for color

has_many :sub_color

end

Comment: You create migrations for each change you wish to make to an entity. You could also create a migration to make multiple related changes to an entity, but that wouldn't reflect best practices. Your phrasing suggests that you're unclear on what a migration is. Now would be a good time to review the [fundamentals](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Comment: Not sure what can be too broad about a question from a junior, who just need a generalized picture. A lot of questions could be too broad if you explain every last detail about an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Rails world! First thing to mention is that Ruby is a language, and Rails is a framework that uses Ruby language. Migrations are a part of Rails and are not a part of Ruby.

Now to your question about migrations. Yes, each table needs migrations for its creation and later migrations for each table adjustment/change, if required (unless you want to do all your table modifications through pure SQL, which you DON'T).

And another part of your question about databases. In a simple case Rails is designed to have 3 databases for 3 different purposes - development, testing, and production. You use the same migrations for all of them. First, you apply your migrations to your local development database and do your code implementation. In parallel, you write tests and also apply the same migrations to your testing database. And when you are done, you deploy everything to your production server and apply your migrations to production database.

I guess it is a general workflow with migrations. As for details, you should really go over [migrations manual](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) or even better to start with ["Getting Started"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) section.